# How to change Public Key in Oracle Cloud

Tags: ubuntu, centos, ssh, oracle, putty

I have `CentOS running on AMD` and `Ubuntu running on ARM` services on Oracle cloud. Previously, I shared my private key (used for connecting SSH/Putty) with my freelance developer. However, over a month later, I noticed unauthorized login attempts.

Since the freelance developer has my private key, they can log in to my server at any time, which is a significant security risk. I have tried to contact them, but I have received no response.

I have searched extensively on YouTube and Google but have not found a proper answer to my question: How can I change the public key in Oracle Cloud, so the freelancer cannot log in again? Once the public key is changed, the private key will also change, making it impossible for them to log in with the old private key.